# Stop trading view widget from redirecting to the website

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using trading view widgets in my react application but I want it to stop from redirecting to the trading view website.
How can I stop from redirecting?

The widget I am using:

```
<MiniChart
  isTransparent="true"
  colorTheme="dark"
  symbol={props.symbol}
  trendLineColor="#2EB086"
  dateRange="1D"
/>
```

[image: The graph is the widget]

When we click on the widget, it redirects to the tradingview application. Any insights?

Comment: See if it has an `onClick` attribute and set it to a null function: `onClick={() => null}`

Comment: It does not have an onClick attribute

Comment: You might be able to use a ref and manually add an "onclick" event listener (remember to remove it on rerenders) to the element. Other than that, the only thing I can think of is the find their source code and remove the `onClick` ¯\\_(ツ)_\/¯

Comment: I don't see a way to disable the click but you can set your own url for the click to visit.  See [largeChartUrl](https://jorrinkievit.github.io/react-ts-tradingview-widgets/docs/components/MiniChart) property.